# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls ~") does not list the contents of home directory

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

this is a Linux machine and the following code does not result in any output, I am curious why. 
P.S. - I didn't read about tilde needing to be escaped but in any case escaped tilde with a backslash and javac pointed out the syntax error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Run {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls ~");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `~` is interpolated by the shell.

Comment: `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ls ~"});` to invoke your shell and expand the `~` before passing it to `ls`.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `~` is replaced with the path to your home directory by the shell. You aren't using the shell. Instead, it's like you ran `ls '~'`, which gives the error:

```
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

In fact, you can see just that happen when you change `p.getInputStream()` to `p.getErrorStream()`, which makes your program output:

```
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `~` interpolated by the shell to get the home folder, instead you can read the `user.home` from system properties like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls " + System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

You could also do it with a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", System.getProperty("user.home"));
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    pb.start().waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```